# How to include non bundle and minified version of js and cs file during debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

i want to load non bundle and non `minified css and js file` in my page when i am testing my web site or running my web site from VS IDE with debug mode but after debug when i will deploy the web site in IIS or run the web site from VS IDE with release mode then then always minified version js and css file should load. just guide me what to do or how to achieve this.

i got a trick for the same from web site http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/08/how-to-use-gulp-in-visual-studio.aspx

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    <!-- Bootstrapping -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/config.js"></script>
    <script src="app/config.exceptionHandler.js"></script>
    <script src="app/config.route.js"></script>
    <!-- app Services -->
    <script src="app/services/datacontext.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/directives.js"></script>
}
else
{
    <script src="app/all.min.js"></script>
}
```

this way we can load non `minified` version of js or css file during running or testing web site from VS IDE with debug mode.

but i believe some kind of feature must be there in IDE itself which does the job. i am working with VS IDE 2013.

### see the code

code taken from http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

what this line does `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; ?`

if some one understand my intention that what i am looking for then please guide me how to achieve this when working with VS IDE 2013/2015

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preprocessor directives` which tells compiler to preprocess before complation takes place.

in `BundleConfig` put this piece of code

```
#if DEBUG
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
 #else
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

Comment: the code u gave if i use it then what will happen when i deploy the site in IIS? minified js and css will load in user pc ? let me know

Comment: @Thomas Yes minified js and css will load in user pc,But make sure you built in `release mode` :)