# Cannot see ASP.NET bundled files in Fiddler

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, bundle, fiddler

There is probably something simple I have missed along the way and for that I will apologize in advance for my potential stupidity.

I am trying to debug what appears to be a stylesheet issue in a web application in VS2015 compared to the same solution/project in VS2013 (same because it was copied from my VS2013 folder to my VS2015 folder).

In the past I used Fiddler regularly and reliably to find missing files or to compare stylesheet and JavaScript files being downloaded.  However, I cannot see a single file when they are bundled.  The only files I can see is if I have included them as specific references on a web page.

I have obviously not kept my knowledge "up to speed" with the current environment and need some advice.

In this bundled world, what should I do to be able to watch, in Fiddler (or some other tool), and see the JavaScript files and stylesheets that are bundled?  There must be someway to have visibility of whether these files are being found and loaded whether they are bundled or not.  Otherwise I wouldn't consider bundling a real step forward -- it may come at a price.

I did see some reference in another [StackOverflow item (35889992)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889992/how-to-include-non-bundle-and-minified-version-of-js-and-cs-file-during-debuggin) to the `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true/false` and have tried that to no avail.

**My specific question:**  Is there a way to gain visibility, either through Fiddler or another tool, of the individual files that have been bundled and downloaded (and whether or not they are all currently available)?

If this has been answered in other forum entries, my apology in advance.  I haven't seen anything that answers this question and delivers a solution.

I am using VS2013 and VS2015, Bootstrap, jQuery, DataTables, etc. (plus my own JavaScript libraries and stylesheet entries) so there is a lot of activity in this area that currently is completely invisible during debugging.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you switch on bundling and optimization, your resources get collected into a single request with a hashed identifier and possibly minimized/obfuscated.

With Fiddler or a web browser you can monitor all network requests to examine these resources.

[image]

You can click on any of these items to see its content and details.

You can also right-click an element in the browser (at least with Chrome) and it will tell you the (bundled) "file" name the styles are attached to.

[image]

Typically, you would only enable optimization *after* you have finished development and debugging.